# Powering Thin Client PC from car's battery

Tags: power-supply, automotive

I have a thin client PC manufactured by HP (t5720). The following specs are written on the power supply:

- Input: 100-240V AC 50-60Hz   2.4A(2,4A)
- Output: 12V DC  4.16A(4,16A)
- Max Output: 50W

I would like to use the thin client in my car, but don't have any power supply for it. Now my thoughts and questions:

- Do I even need some special transformation device as the supply's output is around 12V? The car has between 10.5 and 13 V, depending on whether it's running or not. How tolerant is a device such a thin client? Could this actually damage the car?
- If  I actually need some transformation, what would it be?

There are websites selling such transforming supplies. But some of them cost a lot of money and before buying something I would like to know whether I even need it.

And I wouldn't want to just try it out and plug the thing in before I know what could get damaged. I have some very basic knowledge about electronics but I can't estimate it.

Comment: I thought the ideas of thin clients is that they didn't have hard drives and only a simple OS to load network capabilities, which means no data is stored on the client. So are you going to have a very long network cable attached to you car as well?

Comment: That's the base idea. But did you already have a look at the specs? 1 GHz i686 arch cpu, 512/1024 MB RAM, same for storage. Audio in/output, serial & parallel ports, us, vga. Low power consumption... Tell me if I'm wrong, but that's far enough for a carpc or an embedded system. Why spend more money?

Answer (score 5):

It is very unlikely to damage the car, especially if it is properly fused (I'd fuse both leads), and should work OK as the nominal input is 12V. However, the car is a somewhat hostile environment for electronic equipment, because of the likelihood of high-voltage spikes on the 12V supply. I would use a suitable filter on the supply input to the unit, combined with transient voltage protection, in addition to the fuses. The units you mention would incorporate such protection, and it might be easier to simply buy one of them.

Comment: Keep in mind that computers often have ±5% tolerance on the input line, so that could be a problem for input from alternator. Also, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cigarette_lighter_receptacle)'s a nice article pointing to some problems which could occur.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What kind of filter comes in your mind? As I said, I don't know the electronic-stuff very well, therefore I'd appreciate for example a link to an article, if you have one...

Comment: How are two fuses better than one?

Answer (score 4):

You're probably better off getting an inexpensive automotive inverter to bring the automotive DC up to 120VAC, then using an appropriately-rated AC/DC power supply to generate the 12V you need.

Automotive DC can be very dirty due to the mechanical nature of how it is generated and the non-ideal load characteristics of the rest of the car. Boosting to 120VAC first should help avoid any brown-out issues, plus the inverter will have appropriate protections (fusing/TVS). It should not be hard to find a 12V/5A power supply for the thin client.

Comment: "It should not be hard to find a 12V/5A power supply for the thin client." Do you mean as output? I already have one. But what input specs would this one need?

Comment: "...to bring the automotive DC up to 120VAC" - Does that mean the voltage is 120V? Does this cause any energy "loss"? Doesn't this mean that there's any type of inefficiency?

Comment: The inverter is converting 12VDC to 120VAC, usually a stepped approximation to a sine wave. This is switching conversion, so yes indeed there is some power lost in the process. And yes, the 12V/5A power supply I was talking about would be one that takes 120V input (from the inverter).

Comment: Okay thanks. The supply takes from 100-240V as input. As the voltage here is aroud 230V, therefore it's anyway better to take an inverter for 100-120V than one with output 230V?

Comment: Instead of such a very lossy transformation, if you search now on eBay for something like "DC vehicle power converter" you will find something which transforms vehicle DC -> stable DC directly, and as such more efficiently.

Comment: @atmocreations I'm in North America so all of the automotive inverters I see are 120VAC.

Comment: @miernik He already has the AC-DC power supply (a point I misunderstood from the original post). It's easier to just supply AC to the existing power supply than to get a DC-DC converter and improvise a connection to the client with it.

Comment: Madmanguruman: maybe easier, but it will increase the power consumption probably by at least 10%-20%, maybe more, 5% in the best case, compared the solution with a direct DC-DC converter. If this is in a car, so running off battery, I assume that every bit of power consumption down matters a lot. Unless it will only be used when the car is running, then it doesn't matter. But if it is meant to be able to use the computer without the car engine running, then even a few % down on power consumption is worth the hassle and a bit extra cost.

Comment: I didn't see any mention in the original post concerning doing the conversion in the most efficient manner possible. He has a thin client and an AC power supply, he wants to plug it into his car, and has only very basic electronics experience. Sometimes "good enough" *is* good enough!

Answer (score 1):

[Linear Technology](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/solutions-manual/Linear_Automotive_Brochure_web.pdf) has various parts and app notes that will help.  But I agree with @Leon Heller that the environment is hostile.  I think he is understating it; you may see spikes up to 80 V.